# Rails can't find table after namespacing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue after I moved a model into a rails engine. It is now namespaced under the engine, but I'm getting an error that 'table doesn't exist'. Is there some kind of ActiveRecord caching that I need to clear?

The file used to be in

```
.
└── _app
    └── _models
        └── _foo.rb
```

And it looked like this

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

And:

```
> Foo
=> Foo(id: integer, bar_id: integer)
```

And I moved it to

```
.
└── _components
    └── _my_engine
        └── _app
            └── _models
                └── _my_engine
                    └── _foo.rb
```

And now looks like this:

```
module MyEngine
  class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bar
  end
end
```

And now:

```
> MyEngine::Foo
=> MyEngine::Foo(Table doesn't exist)
> Foo
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
```

My structure.rb looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foos (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    bar_id integer
);
```

Why isn't it recognizing the table anymore?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that Rails was now expecting the table name to be namespaced, as well. So I set my class up to look like this:

```
module MyEngine
  class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'foos'
    self.primary_key = 'id' 

    belongs_to :bar
  end
end
```

..and it worked great.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is downvoted because you would have add the namespace on each model if you do it this way. With @martin-verdejo's answer, you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following file:

```
# app/models/my_engine.rb
module MyEngine
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'my_engine_'
  end
end
```

Make sure that your table is named following conventions.

```
# db/migrate/timestamp_rename_foo_to_my_engine_foos.rb
def change
  rename_table :foos, :my_engine_foos
end
```

Answer (score -1):

here , try using this,  name of class .

```
module MyEngine
  class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bar , class_name: "::#{Rails.application.class.parent_name}::Foo"
  end
end
```